# Why pixel size in browser does not match my display resolution?

Tags: html, macos, pixel, resolution, screen-resolution

I have 2560 x 1600 px resolution on my MacBook and when I make a `div` with size parameters half smaller than my resolution (i.e. 1280 x 800) I expect my browser to use half of the screen surface, but instead it shows zoomed object, how can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height: 800px; width: 1280px; background-color: cyan;">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the **device pixel ratio**: If the DPR is 2 (as for most retina displays), each "CSS pixel" (i.e. the pixel settings you set in CSS) is 2 times as wide and high in device pixels, allowing a finer resoltion for vector-based graphics (including fonts). So you have to divide the real resultion values of a device by that number to get the corresponding CSS pixel value.

In media queries you can also use device pixels, but not in regular CSS rules.

Some more info here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/css-length-explained/

Answer (score 0):

Please check your display scale/ zoom level.
Tip : you can use `vh` and `vw` in css if you want to scale your div relative to our screen size.
`100vh` is full width.